# Reverse the order of listed items in html

Tags: html

I want the latest post to be at the top of the page and the posts listed in descending order.

I have tried this:

```
  @each(post in posts)

         <div class="post-preview">
           <a href="/post/{{ post._id }}">
             <h3 class="post-title">
               {{ post.title }}
             </h3>

           </a>
             <p class="post-meta">Posted by
                 <a href="#">{{ post.username }}</a>
                 on {{ post.createdAt.toDateString() }}
             </p>

         </div>
         <hr>
       @endeach
```

this puts each new blog post under each other. how do i reverse this?

Comment: What language is that? What blog software are you using?

Comment: its not blog software. im desiging a website from scratch for my senior project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't rearrange data itself, you can use `display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;` on parent

Comment: this worked perfectly. thanks. i would have liked to rearrange the data, probably would be a more like "professional" approach. but if it works it works haha. thanks buddy!

Comment: @TimmyGlynn sometimes it's better easier to rearrange the data, sometimes it can be done via css, depends on situation. Happy to know that my answer was useful to you.